# Python - Curve fitting of a 3D cloud of points with intersections

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a cloud of points which represents a contour in 3D, with intersections. The following image shows an example of the type of geometry: you should see two orthogonal circles in 3D, intersecting in 2 points:

[image: curve_3D]

I would like to apply a curve fitting to this geometry, which would give me the contour.
I was thinking of using Numpy or Scipy, but this intersection property makes me get stuck.
Do you have any idea of such function ? If not, any idea how I could use existing fitting functions for this type of geometry.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just represent it as two contours?

Comment: well, it would work in this example, but in reality I am working with a more complicated geometry (a deformed coronary stent). In that case, it is not possible to divide it in plane contours